# Cognito list users multiple filter options

Tags: java, amazon-cognito

I need to call `ListUsersRequest` but for filter I need to pass multiple values as parameters

example wit sql:
`select from users where email IN ('email1', 'email2');`

how I can do that with cognito

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get the users using multiple filters? Thank you